# IiTextSharp why it resizes my image and make it bad quality?

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

I'm trying to insert my image to existing pdf. I'm doing it by this simply code:

```
private void insertBarCodesToPDF(System.Drawing.Image barcode)
    {
        PdfContentByte conent = mPdfStamper.GetOverContent(2);
        byte[] barcodeArray = (byte[]) new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(barcode, typeof(byte[]));

        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(barcodeArray);
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = mPdfStamper.Reader.GetPageSize(2);
        image.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Right - BARCODE_ONLISTPOSITION_X, rect.Top - BARCODE_ONLISTPOSITION_Y);
        conent.AddImage(image);
        mPdfStamper.Close();
        mPdfReader.Close();
    }
```

But after adding I get my image with a very bad qualify and increased size. Check this out:

This is what I need and what I get if I save my Image somewhere by using save() method:

[image: What I need]

And here is what I get in PDF

[image]

What is the problem?? Any ideas?

P.S. original size of image is 138x60, resolution setted to 72dpi.

Comment: Can't you just use vector barcode instead of raster one? Or it's some static file from disk, that you can't generate by yourself?

Comment: *resolution setted to 72dpi* - if displayed on a 96dpi display or printed at 300 dpi, a 72dpi image won't necessarily look good. That been pointed out, can you share a sample PDF with such a bar code for further analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` which means you have absolute fixed pixels that if not shown at the intended resolution will always look weird. As @mkl said above, you can try kicking up the effective DPI of your source image. From the .Net perspective you can ignore the idea of "DPI" and just do everything on a larger scale. I'd start with multiplying your dimensions by 5 giving you 690x300 and see if that looks ok. When you add your new larger image you'll need to scale it back which is where the effective DPI comes in.

```
image.ScaleToFit(138, 60);
```

If you are stuck using your barcode generation code this is the only real solution. However, as @rufanov said, the ***way better*** method would be to actually use a real vector-based barcode and iText ships with just that! Your barcdoe appears to be an ITF barcode so you can just use `iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeInter25`. The below code draws a barcode using the "Arial Unicode MS" font since the default Helvetica that ships with PDF doesn't support Cyrillic characters. You can change this font to whatever you want to use, however. You'll need to readjust rectangles to match your code but otherwise it should work and scale perfectly.

```
//We need a font that supports Cyrillic glyphs
var fontFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF");

//Create an iText font that uses this font
var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontFile, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

//Create our barcode
var B = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeInter25();

//Set the font
B.Font = bf;

//Set the text, you might need to play with the whitespace
B.Code = "693000   78   00700   4";

//Generate an iTextSharp image which is vector-based
var img = B.CreateImageWithBarcode(writer.DirectContent, BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK);

//Shrink the image to fit specific bounds
img.ScaleToFit(100, 100);

//The barcode above doesn't support drawing text on top but we can easily do this
//Also, the OP is using a PdfStamper so this easily works with that path, too

//Create a ColumnText object bound to a canvas.
//For a PdfStamper this would be something like mPdfStamper.GetOverContent(2)
var ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);

//Set the boundaries of the object
ct.SetSimpleColumn(100, 400, 300, 600);

//Add our text using our specified font and size
ct.AddElement(new Paragraph("ПОЧТА РОССИИ", new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10)));

//Add our barcode
ct.AddElement(img);

//Draw the barcode onto the canvas
ct.Go();
```